# Cocos2d-x 3.7 android build error

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I used 3.0rc before. at that time, android build is successful.

but in 3.7 it occurs compile error.

In iOS build is very successful. but android is failed to compile.

```
/Users/RetinaFish/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:393: warning: overriding commands for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/bullet_static/BulletMultiThreaded/SpuLibspe2Support.o'
/Users/RetinaFish/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:393: warning: ignoring old commands for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/bullet_static/BulletMultiThreaded/SpuLibspe2Support.o'
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= AppVariable.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= Bullet.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= CCTBezierRotateTo.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= CCTBezierSpinTo.cpp
In file included from jni/../../Classes/CCTBezierSpinTo.cpp:9:0:
jni/../../Classes/CCTBezierSpinTo.h:12:30: fatal error: CCActionInterval.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CCActionInterval.h"
                              ^
In file included from jni/../../Classes/CCTBezierRotateTo.cpp:9:0:
jni/../../Classes/CCTBezierRotateTo.h:12:30: fatal error: CCActionInterval.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CCActionInterval.h"
                              ^
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/CCTBezierSpinTo.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/CCTBezierRotateTo.o] Error 1
In file included from jni/../../Classes/Ship.h:15:0,
                 from jni/../../Classes/AppVariable.h:15,
                 from jni/../../Classes/AppVariable.cpp:9:
jni/../../Classes/SubShip.h:11:22: fatal error: CCSprite.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CCSprite.h"
                      ^
In file included from jni/../../Classes/Ship.h:15:0,
                 from jni/../../Classes/AppVariable.h:15,
                 from jni/../../Classes/Bullet.cpp:10:
jni/../../Classes/SubShip.h:11:22: fatal error: CCSprite.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CCSprite.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/Bullet.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppVariable.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Projects/PacificWar/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

The above is error shown.

I couldn't understand that it couldn't find CCSprite.h or CCActionInterval.h.

I use both Android Studio and Eclipse. but it doesn't work.

Is there anyone knows how to solve this one?

Comment: Make sure that you have those files. If not then you need to install something. If you have them, make sure they're in the include search path (for the compiler invocation).

Comment: CCSprite.h and CCActionInteval.h is belonging to cocos2d/cocos/2d . Is there any chance to check path?